# How to to set fixed delta time for physics update?

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

I need physics depended on FPS, not delta time. Or how to set fixed delta time, same for every frame for physics?

Answer (score 1):

Blender as far as i know Blender not use delta time for physics, every frame the physics is  re-calculated.

To set the quantity of framerate per second go to `Properties tab > render tab > Display > Animation frame rate`.

To set the physics steps go to `Properties tab > scene tab >Physics > Physics steps``.

[image]